# How to convert Mat object to Bitmap in .NET / C#?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, mat

I m working with image processing in c#. I m taking frames from a camera feed. the type of image frames coming is in Mat. For another function, i need to convert it into Bitmap. 
Please if anyone can help me with that. Couldn't find any solution or converting Mat to Bitmap in c#

Comment: "Mat"? What image type is that? Are you sure this is an image at all?

Comment: @Gusman, apparently it has to do with OpenCV: https://www.google.com/search?q=mat+image+format&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Ok, "MAT" is not an image but a container type. OpenCV seems to be able to handle those, so use OpenCV

Comment: Yeah sorry, its a container type and I m using Emgucv. I know it handles it. But I have tried many methods and conversion codes. Havent been successful. :|

Comment: Yeah, Sorry It's an image container. I m using emgucv and I have tried the built-in methods, functions to convert but haven't been successful. if anyone can help with that,  that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is a very old , but I've encountered the same problem and I've solved it after installing: `Emgu.UI.windows` and now, this code works for me:

```
 var bitmap = Emgu.CV.BitmapExtension.ToBitmap(nextFrame);
```