# How to convert Mat to bitmap in C# using EmguCV?

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

I'm trying to convert Mat to bitmap to open my webcam but with no success. However, I've seen a question with the same context compared to this question but without any answer from the other users : [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270989/how-to-convert-mat-object-to-bitmap-in-net-c) ,

This is the code used :

```
  private void OpenWebcam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    
    {
        var capture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture();

        using (var nextFrame = capture.QueryFrame()) 
        {
            if (nextFrame != null)
            {
                image.Source = nextFrame.ToBitmap(); // error here because there is no ToBitmap method
            }
        }

    }
```

Note that the code I've found in this question [How to get video stream from webcam in emgu cv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727747/how-to-get-video-stream-from-webcam-in-emgu-cv)
  seems to have worked, but I'm using a new version so the method was deleted.

Comment: That requires `Emgu.CV.Bitmap`, but you cannot assign a GDI+ Bitmap to the `.Source` of a Control. You should have `.ToImage<Bgr, byte>()`. Then, see the `System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap()` method and the [DeleteObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject) function.

Comment: I've solved this error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem after installing : `Emgu.UI.windows` and now , this code works for me:

```
 var bitmap = Emgu.CV.BitmapExtension.ToBitmap(nextFrame);
```

Comment: Actually you just need the bitmap extensions. You can find them with the `Emgu.CV.Bitmap` nuget.

Comment: I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: Installing Emgu.UI.Windows is a solution but not the most correct one as you are also installing other nugets that you may not need.
You just need to install the Emgu.CV.Bitmap nuget to use bitmap extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

Simply install Emgu.CV.Bitmap nuget package and  use it like following:

`myimage.ToBitmap()`